# Error in add android to cordova/phonegap project

Tags: android, cordova

I,m unable to add android platform support to phonegap/cordova project.

when I run following command on CLI :
cordova platforms add android

it's giving this error : 
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant' , make sure you have ant installed and added to your path

Comment: Do you have ant installed? Is it added to your PATH environment variable?

Comment: How do I check if it's installed or is added to environment path ?

Comment: You can just type `ant` in your command prompt and it should show you "Buildfile: build.xml does not exist". If it doesn't do that, it means you either didn't install ant or you didn't setup your PATH variables. What does it show you?

Comment: Thanks , did it recognize the ant command then installed ant manually it worked

Answer (score 0):

you need to clean up your eclipse

cd to your eclipse directory and run this command

```
./eclipse -clean
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install Homebrew by executing following command in terminal:

   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
2. Install Apache Ant via Homebrew by executing

   brew install ant
3. Build project

   cordova build android